# Pull variables from sucess page for Google trusted store

Tags: php

i want to pull variables from the order confirmation/sucess page and pass these variables to Google trusted store script. Trusted store script is of this format

MERCHANT_ORDER_ID
  DOMAIN
  CUSTOMER_EMAIL
  CUSTOMER_COUNTRY

  

  
  
  
    ITEM_NAME
    ITEM_PRICE

Has someone implemented Google Trusted Store for Magento? Any kind of help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What have you already tried? You can easily extract this information from the active session/order in success.phtml

Comment: Hi i have tried a script provided by http://www.human-element.com/google-trusted-stores-magento
However, the script doesnot work for extracting email address when the person purchases as a guest

Answer (score 0):

After several modifications, here's what worked for me.

```
<?php
$orderId = $this->getOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId());
$address = $order->getShippingAddress();
$backorder = false; // some backorder logic
$download = false; // some download logic
$shipDate = new Zend_Date(); // some logic to determine ship date
?>

<div id="gts-order" style="display:none;">
    <span id="gts-o-id"><?php echo $orderId; ?></span>
    <span id="gts-o-domain">www.yourdomain.com</span>
    <span id="gts-o-email"><?php echo htmlentities($customer->getEmail()); ?></span>
    <span id="gts-o-country">US</span>
    <span id="gts-o-currency">USD</span>
    <span id="gts-o-total"><?php echo (round($order->getGrandTotal(),2)); ?></span>
    <span id="gts-o-discounts"><?php echo (round($order->getDiscountAmount(),2)); ?></span>
    <span id="gts-o-shipping-total"><?php echo (round($order->getShippingAmount(),2)); ?></span>
    <span id="gts-o-tax-total"><?php echo (round($order->getTaxAmount(),2)); ?></span>
    <span id="gts-o-est-ship-date"><?php echo $shipDate->toString('yyyy-MM-dd'); ?></span>
    <span id="gts-o-has-preorder"><?php echo $backorder ? 'Y' : 'N'; ?></span>
    <span id="gts-o-has-digital"><?php echo $download ? 'Y' : 'N'; ?></span>
    <?php foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item): ?>
        <span class="gts-item">
          <span class="gts-i-name"><?php echo htmlentities($item->getName()); ?></span>
          <span class="gts-i-price"><?php echo (round($item->getBasePrice(),2)); ?></span>
          <span class="gts-i-quantity"><?php echo (int)$item->getQtyOrdered(); ?></span>
          <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-id">ITEM_GOOGLE_SHOPPING_ID</span>
          <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-store-id">ITEM_GOOGLE_SHOPPING_ACCOUNT_ID</span>
          <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-country">US</span>
          <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-language">en</span>
        </span>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<!-- END Trusted Stores -->
```